# Itunes Connect test flight public link validity

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect, itunes, testflight

Apple has recently enabled public link feature for test flight builds, we can share this link with anyone and he can install the app using this public link.

The validity of the build behind this public link is 90 days. My question is, after sharing the public link with the users can we increase the expiry time of the build?  So that the validity of public link gets increased and we do not have to ship another build after 90 days and share the new link with users.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got the answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the answer, the build expires after 90 days but link do not, when you upload the new build on a test flight for testing then the old public link **remains unchanged** for this new build.

So, your public link will remain valid even if you upload new build.

Comment: So, the same old link will not give the new build to test right ?