# Test Flight Beta : Public Link URL will it change for every upload?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, beta-testing, testflight-public-link

I have shared a [Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) - Public link with testers. Now I am going to upload a new build (same app version, but new build number). **Once it gets approved - Do we get a new Public test link or same old link will work ?**

Comment: As @abuzer says, it will remain unchanged : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55119358/3632832

Comment: No, Every tester will get notified when you will upload and submit your build for testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same link will work. The tester can choose which build he wants to test. You will have to enable public link for every build in "Groups" under the test flight tab for your app which you want to be available for public testing.

[image]